# Pixi js Tiling sprite repeating in all axis

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I've got a problem that I can't solve on my own. I've created a scene using fragments of a PNG image in Pixi.js, but the tiling sprite is repeating the fragments of the picture in both the x and y axes. You can see what I mean in this picture:
[I feel palpable pain when I see this scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL2ya.png)

I`m using Pixi.js 5+

Here is my code:

```
  createTilingSprite(){
    const texture = Texture.from(this.spriteName);
    const tilingSprite = new TilingSprite(
      texture,
      window.innerWidth,
      window.innerHeight
    )
    tilingSprite.position.set(0, 0)
    return tilingSprite;
}
```

I`ve tried uvMatrix, and MarginCla,p, but this propertes are set for another circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the only way to solve this problem is to use the **scaling method** in PIXI.

```
createTilingSprite() {
    const tilingSprite = new TilingSprite(
        this.texture,
        this.width,
        this.height
    );
    tilingSprite.position.set(0, 0);
    tilingSprite.scale.set(
        document.body.clientHeight/this.height,
    );
    return tilingSprite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the repetition of fragments in both the x and y axes when using a TilingSprite in Pixi.js, you can adjust the uvTransform property of the texture.

Try this:

```
createTilingSprite() {
  const texture = Texture.from(this.spriteName);
  texture.baseTexture.wrapMode = WRAP_MODES.CLAMP; // Set wrap mode to clamp

  const tilingSprite = new TilingSprite(
    texture,
    window.innerWidth,
    window.innerHeight
  );
  tilingSprite.position.set(0, 0);
  return tilingSprite;
}
```

Dont forget to import:

```
import { TilingSprite, Texture, WRAP_MODES } from 'pixi.js';
```

Comment: I appreciate thy effort to assist me, but it seems that Pixi doth repeat the image in both axes, and the only way to solve this issue is by using the scaling method. I attempted thy solution, but it hath not made any difference.